# How to add cs50.h directory to VSCode?

Tags: cs50

The program I want to write:    hello.c

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string answer = get_string("What's your name?");
    printf("hello, answer\n");
}
```

I get a message (cs50.h: No such file or directory)

Comment: In order to use CS50's library for C, you have to download and install it first. As the installation depends on your Operating System, it is better to follow their guide: https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/

Answer (score 1):

1. download `cs50.c` and `cs50.h` from this link: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/main/src
   and move theme to your project directory.
2. include cs50.c :

   #include "cs50.c"

   #include <stdio.h>